# Pause Emscripten SDL audio immediately without a delay

Tags: javascript, c++, sdl, web-audio-api, emscripten

When I call `SDL_PauseAudio(1)` in an Emscripten-compiled C++ enviroment, there is a delay of about a second or so before the sound stops coming out of the speakers.

How can this delay be avoided, and the pause effected immediately?

The C++ code is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <emscripten.h>
#include <SDL_audio.h>

using std::cerr;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

int count = 0;
int paused = true;

void getMoreAudio(void *, Uint8 *stream, int len) {
  for (auto i=0; i<len; i++) {
    stream[i] = static_cast<Uint8>(sin((count + i) * M_PI / 400.00) * 128);
  }
  count = count + len;
}

extern "C" EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE void togglePause() {
  paused = !paused;
  SDL_PauseAudio(paused ? 1 : 0);
}

int main() {
  SDL_AudioSpec desired;
  SDL_AudioSpec obtained;
  desired.freq = 48000;
  desired.format = AUDIO_U8; 
  desired.channels = 1;
  desired.samples = 4096;
  desired.padding = 0;
  desired.size = 8192;
  desired.callback = &getMoreAudio;
  desired.userdata = nullptr;
  auto res = SDL_OpenAudio(&desired, &obtained);
  SDL_PauseAudio(paused ? 1 : 0);

  emscripten_set_main_loop([](){}, 0, false);
  return 0;
}
```

And I've setup a Plunker at http://plnkr.co/edit/O4XbXYBXHg4ZwUWB5puY?p=preview . Starting the audio by pressing the buttons seems immediate, but then pausing does not.

I've observed delay in Chrome on Linux + Mac.

Comment: can it be just the speakers/reaction time? how can you check and make sure when the audio actually stops?

Comment: @Vladp I can just pause other audio immediately (say, from iTunes), so I don't think it's something built into the hardware. Regarding checking, not sure what you mean... I can hear the audio carry on, but I have no objective test to determine exactly for how long. It feels like a second, or a bit shorter.

Comment: post the rest of the code

Comment: @Vladp Added some code, admittedly not much: not sure what will help.

Comment: @Vladp And now a fuller example, with a link to a working Plunker

Comment: `SDL_PauseAudio` seems to just stop next  getMoreAudio call. https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/9a3839a6dc3665db38eba8dd9f7bd99eee9ac957/src/library_sdl.js#L2479

Comment: like zakki said. try this instead https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PauseAudioDevice

Comment: @Vladp I don't think `SDL_PauseAudioDevice` is implemented in Emscripten. Doing a grep for it in the repository comes up with nothing other than the declaration in `SDL_audio.h` (while I can see the code for `SDL_PauseAudio`)